# .htaccess file not running and internal server error

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-10.04, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and have LAMP environment. I have one of the project in dir **/var/www/html/project1** . It can't access the **.htaccess** file for rewriting url rules.

For that i have to change in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All       # change None to All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
      Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

But after this change my Apache server gives an error "Internal Server error" and apache give error for any website (project).

And If I'll change **'AllowOverride None'** then site is running correctly But .htaccess file doesn't work.

The **'Internal Server Error'** is due to .htaccess file in another project which is like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I can't understand anything in htaccess file.
Plz help me in to rewrite the htaccess file and meaning of the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the directive in the default  block you should use a separate block specifically for your project directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/project1>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This will only allow .htaccess files to be used in this specific directory.

The 500 error that you are getting is probably due to some bad syntax in a .htaccess file. It would be helpful if you showed us what you have in all of the .htaccess files.

Alternatively you can look in the Apache error logs at /var/log/apache2/error.log for more specific information about the error.

Comment: Thanks, It solves my problem. But I guess one of my htaccess file cause **Internal Server error** 
this is as bellow